# How to solve unexpected token { syntax error in JSON in javascript

Tags: javascript, python, json

```
"{  \"nodes\":   
    {      \"name\": \"Enron Announcements\",      \"counts\": {        \"name\": \"Enron Announcements\",        \"role\": \"employee\",        \"team_name\": \"Ufone\",        \"oversees\": \"\",        \"reports_to\": \"Zimin Lu,Lorna Brennan\",        \"unique_threads\": \"366\"      },      \"bridgeScore\": 0.0    
    },  

   {      \"name\": \"Enron worldwide\",      \"counts\": {        \"name\": \"Enron Announcements\",        \"role\": \"employee\",        \"team_name\": \"Ufone\",        \"oversees\": \"\",        \"reports_to\": \"Zimin Lu,Lorna Brennan\",        \"unique_threads\": \"366\"      },      \"bridgeScore\": 0.0    
    },  ...}
```

Above mentioned is what my JSON looks like. It is giving error that unexpected token { in Json. This error is thrown before name:Enron worldwide (before second one starts). How do I get rid of this error?

This is how I generated the JSON string:

```
for i in graph.nodes():
        if "nan" not in str(i):

                nodes.append({'name': str(i), 'counts': user_data[str(i)], 'bridgeScore':bridgeScore[str(i)]})

        links = [{'source': u[0], 'target': u[1]}
             for u in graph.edges()]
        for u in graph.edges():
            print(u)
             # with open('graph.json', 'w') as f:
        # return G
        graph_json = json.dumps({'nodes': nodes, 'links': links},indent=2,)
        graph_json = str(graph_json).replace("\n","")
        graph_json = str(graph_json).replace("[","")
        graph_json = str(graph_json).replace("]","")
        graph_json = str(graph_json).replace("\\","")
        with open('temp.json','w') as fp:
                json.dump(graph_json , fp)
```

PS: json is generated through python and is to be rendered in JS

Comment: The error means that the JSON is invalid. The way to deal with this is ensure the backend returns valid JSON.

Comment: How do I do that? I tried printing it in a file and see what the error is about. I have shared the error here. Does { seem wrong?

Comment: It seems strange that you have a multiline string quoted by one quote... How did you generate this? That would be the thing to change... Are you aware of the json module?

Comment: @ThierryLathuille I have added the explanation

Comment: You have a structure like this: `{  "nodes": {}, {} }`. Yes, this is invalid. You seem to want an array here.

Comment: Please share the valid output

Comment: Why are you manually manipulating the `graph_json` after a `json.dumps`?? No wonder you're getting syntax errors.

Comment: @Krrr to resolve previous error that it threw

Comment: `str(graph_json).replace("[","")`? `str(graph_json).replace("]","")`???

Comment: Don't try to manage quoting and so on yourself. Build the data structure you want and export it using the `json` module that will take care of that.

Comment: It added an [ bracket right after first { and that threw error so I removed that

Comment: @ThierryLathuille Let me post the error that I got previously that made me add these replaces

Comment: I still don't understand why you would remove `[` and `]` as they are part of the integral structure of your json.  Let the `json` module do the formatting for you, leave it alone.  And don't `dumps` and then `dump` it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're encoding JSON twice. In your code, remove everything after the `# return G` line and replace it with:

```
graph_json = {'nodes': nodes, 'links': links}
with open('temp.json','w') as fp:
        json.dump(graph_json , fp, indent=2)
```

If you need to remove `nan` values from `links`, you can do it like this:

```
links = [
    {'source': u[0], 'target': u[1]}
    for u in graph.edges()
    if not math.isnan(u[0]) and not math.isnan(u[1])
]
```

(don't forget to `import math`)

Comment: getting this error : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token N in JSON at position 54068 because of this {"source": NaN, "target": NaN}, How do I get rid of this

Comment: Don't output `NaN` as a value, as it's not valid in JSON.

Comment: @VLAZ: this is what `json.dumps` does (unless you provide `allow_nan=False`, in which case it breaks ;)

Comment: @FatimaArshad: you have to remove NaN values before encoding them as JSON, see https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.isnan

Comment: @georg that seems odd. I assume `json` is the library/functionality that generates JSON? If so, I wouldn't expect it to produce *incorrect* JSON.

Comment: I try adding a condition in  loop for links like this : if "NaN" not in u[0] and "NaN" not in u[1]: but it is giving this error TypeError: argument of type 'float' is not iterable.  I realize it is going off topic but it'd be very helpful

Comment: Your `u[0]` and `u[1]` are both floats, the `in` operator doesn't apply.  You might want to change your `NaN` to `None` instead.  It's odd though, I was able to do a `loads` and `dumps` of data containing `NaN`.

Comment: @VLAZ: yes, this looks like a flaw in the `json` module. At least, they could make the strict mode default, that is `allow_nan=False`.

Comment: I tried that one earlier too but this is the error that I get :/ TypeError: must be real number, not str

Comment: Tried doing this: if "NaN" not in str(u[0]) and "NaN" not in str(u[1]) and the error persists

Comment: This worked if "nan" not in  str(u[0]) and  "nan" not in str(u[1]):